# 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '***.database.windows.net:3306' (10060)

Tags: python, mysql, azure-sql-database, mysql-connector-python

I am trying to connect Azure SQL database using **mysql-connector-python** library.
But I am getting above mentioned error.
Here I am attaching my code for reference.
I have been given access to my IP in the firewall.

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode

# Obtain connection string information from the portal


# Construct connection string
config = {
  'host':'db.database.windows.net',
  'user':'server@db',
  'password':'********',
  'database':'db',
  'client_flags': [mysql.connector.ClientFlag.SSL],
  'ssl_ca': 'DigiCertGlobalRootG2.crt.pem'
}

try:
   conn = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
   print("Connection established")
except mysql.connector.Error as err:
  if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
    print("Something is wrong with the user name or password")
  elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
    print("Database does not exist")
  else:
    print(err)
else:
  cursor = conn.cursor()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the MySQL connector to connect to an Azure SQL database.  There's a difference between a [MySQL database](https://www.mysql.com/) and an [Azure SQL database](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/azure-sql/).

#### Azure SQL IS NOT MySQL

You can either use [Azure Database for MySQL](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/mysql) as a database, or check out this example on how to [Use Python to query a SQL database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/connect-query-python), which uses an ODBC driver. As you can see in the linked article, they exist for macOS, Ubuntu and Windows.

```
import pyodbc
server = '<server>.database.windows.net'
database = '<database>'
username = '<username>'
password = '{<password>}'   
driver= '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'

with pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER=tcp:'+server+';PORT=1433;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password) as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("SELECT TOP 3 name, collation_name FROM sys.databases")
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        while row:
            print (str(row[0]) + " " + str(row[1]))
            row = cursor.fetchone()
```

Comment: Earlier I was trying to connect with pyodbc, but I had an issue installing it in docker. That's why I referred to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/connect-python) document to connect using MySQL connector.

Comment: @BhavsikAhir The link you posted is a link to an article on how to "connect and query data in Azure Database for MySQL". You're not using a MySQL database but a SQL database. Those are two different things.